# How to fix Application Defined or Object Defined Error for this specific line of code?

Tags: excel, vba

Can't seem to make the code work despite using spacing and operators around the code, can't pinpoint exact where the problem lies

Tried placing operators many times but still ended up with errors for example Expected: end of statement, as such this is the line of code that was highlighted:

```
userMsheet.Cells(lastrow + 1, "A").Formula = "=HYPERLINK(" & "#" & 
ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & Cells(salesNo - 1, 3).Address & "," & 
usernameComboBox.Value & ")"
```

Expected Result: The code should create a hyperlink in another worksheet when this button in the userform is pressed

Comment: Where does this link point to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SubAddress Issue not feat. #

I don't think that what you two are trying to do is even possible. Therefore I would suggest you add the hyperlink directly into the cell i.e. if you want it to point to something.

> ```
>   userMsheet.Hyperlinks.Add _
>       anchor:=userMsheet.Cells(lastrow + 1, "A"), _
>       Address:="", _
>       SubAddress:="'" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!" _
>           & Cells(salesNo - 1, 3).Address, _
>       TextToDisplay:=usernameComboBox.Value
> ```

EDIT: Here is what I'm using:

```
Sub whatever()

  ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add _
      anchor:=Range("A6"), _
      Address:="", _
      SubAddress:="'" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!" & Cells(6, 3).Address, _
      TextToDisplay:="Whatever"

End Sub
```

Your Code:

```
With userMsheet
  lastrow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  .Hyperlinks.Add _
  anchor:=.Cells(lastrow + 1, "A"), _
  Address:="", _
  SubAddress:="'" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!" _
      & Cells(salesNo - 1, 3).Address, _
  TextToDisplay:=usernameComboBox.Value
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Will try the code now, could not get back to u earlier due to Christmas! Merry Christmas btw!

Comment: Code has an error stating Invalid procedure call or argument. Is it even possible to do a hyperlink in this case? I feel that it is impossible...

Comment: @beginnercoder123: I have double checked, it has to be working. Have you checked the variables and the worksheets? I've edited the answer. So try this and if it works adjust your variables, worksheets etc.

Comment: With userMsheet

    lastrow = userMsheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
      userMsheet.Hyperlinks.Add _
      anchor:=userMsheet.Cells(lastrow + 1, "A"), _
      Address:="", _
      SubAddress:="'" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!" _
          & Cells(salesNo - 1, 3).Address, _
      TextToDisplay:=usernameComboBox.Value
    

    End With

Comment: Error is highlighted from userMsheet.hyperlinks.add ...... until TextToDisplay:= usernameCombo.Box. I have already defined all the necessary variables, can't seem to figure out the issue here

Comment: @beginnercoder123: Should work. Are you sure that salesNo is greater than 1?Does usernameComboBox exist i.e. that it isn't nothing? In any case you should try the 'Whatever' code to prove if it is working on your computer. Just open a new workbook, put in the code and run it. You should get a hyperlink in A6 called Whatever and when clicking on it it will jump to C6.

Comment: Tried it on new workbook, code works. But I can't fine tuned it with variables like mine as intended. Yes, salesNo is greater than 1, and usernameComboBox exist in the userform. I really cannot seem to figure out the issue here..

Comment: @beginnercoder123: Maybe you have to use Userform1.UsernameComboBox or whatever the name of the  userform is.

Comment: It worked!!! Apparently, the issue was in front of the code, I had codes to clear each value of the inputs, for eg ComboBox.Text = "", thus the hyperlink was deemed invalid. My mistake, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Is it also possible that if I delete the name on the activesheet, will the  name on the other sheet be deleted as well? Is there any function to make that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```
userMsheet.Cells(lastrow + 1, "A").Formula = "=HYPERLINK(" & _
ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & Cells(salesNo - 1, 3).Address & "," & _
Chr(34) & usernameComboBox.Value & Chr(34) & ")"
```

Comment: Good catch! I tested the code with value instead of variable and forgot to put variable here. So it would be `salesNo`.

Comment: I need to add the "#" in front of the hyperlink, is it possible to do so? Thanks in advance. To be more specific I need to add the "#" infront of the activesheet.name otherwise, that code will prompt me with a file explorer which i do not want

Comment: @beginnercoder123 You can add but it will not work as hyperlink then. Can you explain why you need to add hash # symbol?

Comment: To add hash just use like `= "=HYPERLINK(#" & …..`

Comment: Why will it not work as hyperlink? I searched online on how to put hyperlink in formula in VBA it shows a "#" symbol in front of the sheet name. The code works but it will always open a file explorer stating UPDATE VALUES, which I want to avoid. Hope this clarifies your question

Comment: @beginnercoder123 then you can use `= "=HYPERLINK(#" & …..`

Comment: Yea I tried that by adding it front of the " but it stills prompt me with application defined or object defined error, I really do not know what is the problem... Is something wrong with my variables or something? I alr set userMsheet at the top as worksheet already, I am out of ideas it seems

Comment: @beginnercoder123 when you manually create the hyperlink by typing `=HYPERLINK...` into the cell, does it work with the `#`? It doesn't look like it should according to the [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/hyperlink-function-333c7ce6-c5ae-4164-9c47-7de9b76f577f)

Comment: @BigBen Hi, yea. I tried creating a macro as well as searching up online. It seems to have a "#" symbol when trying to hyperlink to other sheets in the same workbook